# VirtualBox on Fedora 31 can not be set up. Packages missing

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I am running fedora 31 and grabbed virtualbox from RPM fusion but I have not been able to find a way to get it working.

The error when starting a VM is:

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is probably not
>   loaded.You may not have kernel driver installed for kernel that is
>   runnig, if so you may do as root: dnf install akmod-VirtualBox
>   kernel-devel-$(uname -r)If you installed VirtualBox packages and don't
>   want reboot the system, you may need load the kernel driver, doing as
>   root: akmods; systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
>   the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
>   you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
>   more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
>   support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT

I have attempted to install the package requested but it does not exist

```
$ sudo dnf install akmod-VirtualBox kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
Last metadata expiration check: 0:39:48 ago on Tue 18 Feb 2020 09:43:31 ACDT.
Package akmod-VirtualBox-6.1.2-1.fc31.x86_64 is already installed.
No match for argument: kernel-devel-5.4.13-201.fc31.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-devel-5.4.13-201.fc31.x86_64
```

Has this package been renamed to something else or does it not exist anymore?

```
$ rpm -qa | grep kernel
kernel-headers-5.4.7-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-devel-5.4.18-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-modules-5.4.18-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-modules-5.4.12-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-5.4.12-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-modules-5.4.13-201.fc31.x86_64
kernel-modules-extra-5.4.13-201.fc31.x86_64
kernel-devel-5.4.15-200.fc31.x86_64
libreport-plugin-kerneloops-2.12.0-1.fc31.x86_64
kernel-core-5.4.12-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-core-5.4.13-201.fc31.x86_64
kernel-5.4.13-201.fc31.x86_64
kernel-modules-extra-5.4.18-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-core-5.4.18-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-modules-extra-5.4.12-200.fc31.x86_64
kernel-5.4.18-200.fc31.x86_64
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.14.0-1.fc31.x86_64

$ yum list available | grep kernel
R-IRkernel.noarch                                                          1.0.2-1.fc31                                               fedora                   
buildsys-build-rpmfusion-kerneldevpkgs-current.x86_64                      11:31-3                                                    rpmfusion-free-updates   
erlang-kernel.x86_64                                                       22.2.6-2.fc31                                              updates                  
gap-pkg-jupyterkernel.noarch                                               1.3-2.fc31                                                 fedora                   
gap-pkg-jupyterkernel-doc.noarch                                           1.3-2.fc31                                                 fedora                   
kernel-cross-headers.x86_64                                                5.4.7-200.fc31                                             updates                  
kernel-debug.x86_64                                                        5.4.18-200.fc31                                            updates                  
kernel-debug-core.x86_64                                                   5.4.18-200.fc31                                            updates                  
kernel-debug-devel.x86_64                                                  5.4.18-200.fc31                                            updates                  
kernel-debug-modules.x86_64                                                5.4.18-200.fc31                                            updates                  
kernel-debug-modules-extra.x86_64                                          5.4.18-200.fc31                                            updates                  
kernel-debug-modules-internal.x86_64                                       5.4.18-200.fc31                                            updates                  
kernel-modules-internal.x86_64                                             5.4.18-200.fc31                                            updates                  
kernel-rpm-macros.noarch                                                   142-1.fc31                                                 updates                  
kernel-tools.x86_64                                                        5.4.7-200.fc31                                             updates                  
kernel-tools-libs.i686                                                     5.3.7-300.fc31                                             fedora                   
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64                                                   5.4.7-200.fc31                                             updates                  
kernel-tools-libs-devel.i686                                               5.3.7-300.fc31                                             fedora                   
kernel-tools-libs-devel.x86_64                                             5.4.7-200.fc31                                             updates                  
kernelshark.x86_64                                                         2.7-7.fc31                                                 fedora                   
lirc-disable-kernel-rc.noarch                                              0.10.0-18.fc31                                             fedora                   
php-symfony-http-kernel.noarch                                             2.8.52-1.fc31                                              updates                  
php-symfony3-http-kernel.noarch                                            3.4.37-1.fc31                                              updates                  
php-symfony4-http-kernel.noarch                                            4.2.11-1.fc31                                              fedora                   
python-ipykernel-doc.noarch                                                5.1.2-1.fc31                                               fedora                   
python-metakernel-doc.noarch                                               0.24.3-1.fc31                                              fedora                   
python3-ipykernel.noarch                                                   5.1.2-1.fc31                                               fedora                   
python3-jupyter-c-kernel.noarch                                            1.2.2-5.fc31                                               fedora                   
python3-jupyter-kernel-singular.noarch                                     0.9.9-1.fc31                                               updates                  
python3-jupyter-kernel-test.noarch                                         0.3-10.fc31                                                fedora                   
python3-metakernel.noarch                                                  0.24.3-1.fc31                                              fedora                   
python3-metakernel-echo.noarch                                             0.19.1-28.fc31                                             fedora                   
python3-metakernel-python.noarch                                           0.19.1-28.fc31                                             fedora                   
python3-metakernel-tests.noarch                                            0.24.3-1.fc31                                              fedora                   
python3-octave-kernel.noarch                                               0.31.0-3.fc31                                              fedora                   
python3-spyder-kernels.noarch                                              1:0.5.2-2.fc31                                             fedora                   
texlive-l3kernel.noarch                                                    9:svn51745-15.fc31                                         updates                  
texlive-l3kernel-doc.noarch                                                9:svn51745-15.fc31                                         updates
```

Comment: Add the output of `rpm -qa | grep kernel` and `yum list available | grep kernel` to your question.

Comment: @NasirRiley done

Answer (score 0):

You already have the latest version of `kernel` and `kernel-devel` installed which is `5.4.18-200`. `uname -r` is still giving you `5.4.13-201` so you need to reboot your machine. When it comes back up, `uname -r` will give you `5.4.18-200`. Load the module with `vboxdrv` and see if it appears with `lsmod | grep vbox`.

If it doesn't load at boot, create the file `/etc/modules-load.d/vboxdrv.conf` with `vboxdrv` inside. That will load it at boot. Once that's done, you'll be able to launch Virtual Box and start a VM.